# Facebook page access token doesn't show page feed results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using a system user access token I can make an unpublished post to the feed just fine and I can receive a page access token for that page. However, when I attempt to read the feed using the page access token (from a system user) I receive an empty data result, that is I don't see any posts at all or even my newly created unpublished post.

Per the [Graph API 2.1 documentation for read page feeds](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed#read) I should be able to use a page access token to retrieve all posts on the page.

Here are my steps:

1. GET request to /v2.1/me/accounts using system user access token, result includes access token
2. POST request with page accesss token to /{page-id}/feed with fields published "false" & message "test", result is post ID (I can verify this post using object id on the graph api)
3. GET request with page access token to /{page-id}/feed and result is {"data":[]}

If I GET request to /{page-id}/feed with my user access token I'm shown all published posts fine.

What's wrong with my steps or assumptions?

Comment: Have you tried /{page-id}/promotable_posts ?

Comment: /{page-id}/promotable_posts returns empty data response using page access token but using my user access token it does return posts including the unpublished post.

Comment: I would suggest that you file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks WizKid, I took your suggestion and FB is now investigating. Bug ticket is https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/581600435301718/